# Force a full page reload in Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I use **Livewire** and **Alpine** with **Laravel 8**.

I have a page with a **Datatable (jQuery)** and a Bootstrap modal.
The table is filled with some data from a list of model instances.
When I click on a button in the table, it opens the modal and allows to edit the corresponding record.
This part is working as expected.

However, the **Datatable** library is much more to difficult to use with Livewire, so I decided to scope the entire **Datatable** in a `<div>` with `wire:ignore` attribute.
Because of that, If I want to refresh the **Datatable** when a modification has been made, I can't use the magic `$refresh` because the **Datatable** is currently scoped inside `wire:ignore`.

So I was thinking about making a full page reload after the edit is done, but I did not figure out how to do this, `return redirect()->back()` is not working...

This is what my `save` method looks like, which is called when an edit from the modal is done:

```
public function save()
{
    MyModel::where('id', $this->edited_id)->update([...]);
    $this->clearSelection();
    return redirect()->back(); // This is not working
}
```

And this is my table:

```
<div wire:ignore>
    <table class="dt-table table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Actions</th>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>other</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($models as $m)
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">Edit</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ $m->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $m->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $m->somedata }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: try `location.reload();`

Comment: @KamleshPaul You mean calling Javascript to init a page reload. I wonder if there is a solution directly inside Livewire component (in PHP) like a redirect() or something

Answer (score 38):

Livewire stores the original URL in the `Referer` header. You can use it to refresh the page:

```php
return redirect(request()->header('Referer'));
```

Answer (score 4):

In Livewire v3, you can use the `js()` method to evaluate smaller, individual JavaScript expressions:

```php
$this->js('window.location.reload()');
```

See the [docs](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/actions#evaluating-one-off-javascript-expressions) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Check you're using Livewire version 2.x.x and you should be able to follow the docs here:

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/redirecting

Livewire component:

```
class ContactForm extends Component
{
    public $email;

    public function addContact()
    {
        Contact::create(['email' => $this->email]);

        return redirect()->to('/contact-form-success');
    }
}
```

Livewire component template

```
<div>
    Email: <input wire:model="email">

    <button wire:click="addContact">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So I should redirect to itself ?

Comment: Yes. I usually just redirect to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `url()->previous()` in Livewire component, that's it.

Answer (score -1):

In the view that includes the currency component

```
@livewire('nav-cart',['page'=>request()->fullUrl()])
```

Then in the component, the mounting method

```
public function mount($page)
    {

        $this->page = $page;
```

create a public property $page, and then after changing the currency

```
return redirect($this->page);
```